# formating lines in the paragraphs

Tags: line-breaking, paragraphs, document-classes

I'm writing report in latex .But my document appear with not good style all lines in paragraphs not in same length >How to get that ?

edit:

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}


\pagestyle{empty} %No headings for the first pages.

\tableofcontents 
\pagestyle{plain}

\flushleft
\clearpage
 \chapter*{Dedication}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
%\begin{Dedication}

First,we  thank God for His blessings and to reconcile and repaid during these years that have passed us to get to this stage of science, knowledge and culture.

We thank our parents on a continuous effort and giving and  permanent support to reach  Achievements.
 \clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: any clues as to what the input looks like?

Comment: please check the edit

Comment: the `\newline` at the end is wrong and should be deleted but apart from that we can tell nothing from that fragment, please make a small _complete_ one-page document that shows the problem, oh you have `\newline` all over. Delete them all.

Comment: Remove that `\flushleft`

Comment: so the question was entirely about a command that you had given no hint was in your document, `\flushleft` (which should never be used as a command always as `\begin{flushleft}`...`\end{flushleft}`  says to preserve the left margin only and not the right.

Answer (score 2):

Hard to guess what output you want, three alternatives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{description}
  \item[In nature,] clustering is a mechanism for solving  diversity and 
complexity things from simple and basic elements.
    In IT field: is a good concept and technique to use existing component 
hardware or software to accomplish specific goal with special  characteristics
 (cost, time, performance at all).
 \item[The history] of the cluster usage begin in largest computers in the
 world , But clusters are also playing important roles in technical and commerce
 computing, taking advantage of low cost, complex market PC-based computer 
technology. These  
    Beowulf-cluster systems have Become too popular, play the best role in
 reducing cost, area needed for the environment, time for 
    execution, on the other side it increased the performance and extended
   the scope for most of the net based application, Flexibility
    Configuration and promotion, and the ability to provide new and powerful
 tool, and open new opportunities for the whole computing applications.
\end{description}

\bigskip



  \textbf{In nature,} clustering is a mechanism for solving  diversity and 
complexity things from simple and basic elements.
    In IT field: is a good concept and technique to use existing component 
hardware or software to accomplish specific goal with special  characteristics
 (cost, time, performance at all).

\textbf{The history} of the cluster usage begin in largest computers in the
 world , But clusters are also playing important roles in technical and commerce
 computing, taking advantage of low cost, complex market PC-based computer 
technology. These  
    Beowulf-cluster systems have Become too popular, play the best role in
 reducing cost, area needed for the environment, time for 
    execution, on the other side it increased the performance and extended
   the scope for most of the net based application, Flexibility
    Configuration and promotion, and the ability to provide new and powerful
 tool, and open new opportunities for the whole computing applications.


\bigskip

  \paragraph{In nature,} clustering is a mechanism for solving  diversity and 
complexity things from simple and basic elements.
    In IT field: is a good concept and technique to use existing component 
hardware or software to accomplish specific goal with special  characteristics
 (cost, time, performance at all).

\paragraph{The history} of the cluster usage begin in largest computers in the
 world , But clusters are also playing important roles in technical and commerce
 computing, taking advantage of low cost, complex market PC-based computer 
technology. These  
    Beowulf-cluster systems have Become too popular, play the best role in
 reducing cost, area needed for the environment, time for 
    execution, on the other side it increased the performance and extended
   the scope for most of the net based application, Flexibility
    Configuration and promotion, and the ability to provide new and powerful
 tool, and open new opportunities for the whole computing applications.



\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have added `\flushleft` that disables justification. Hence remove it.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\begin{document}


\pagestyle{empty} %No headings for the first pages.

\tableofcontents
\pagestyle{plain}

%\flushleft   %%<- remove
\clearpage
 \chapter*{Dedication}
 \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Dedication}
%\begin{Dedication}
\Centering
First,we  thank God for His blessings and to reconcile and repaid during these years that have passed us to get to this stage of science, knowledge and culture.

We thank our parents on a continuous effort and giving and  permanent support to reach  Achievements.
 \clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I use \center command before that paragraph , how to enable justification

Comment: @sepeee Add `\usepackage{ragged2e}` and use `\Centering` instead of `\centering`. Not `C` instead of `c`.